# c# 2 Parameters save in xml

Tags: c#, xml

i want to save an ID (integer) and an String in one XML Document. How can i do this with c# code?

I know it for one object , but i have no idea how to do it for 2.

Here my code for one object:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument ReleasesXML;

    if (File.Exists(id + ".xml"))
    {
        ReleasesXML = XDocument.Load(id + ".xml");
    }
    else
    {
        File.Copy("SourcefileReleases.Xml", id + ".xml");
        ReleasesXML = XDocument.Load(id + ".xml");
    }
```

I found this way to manage this Problem

Now i tried this code:

```
Dictionary dict = new Dictionary();
    XElement elBookmark = new XElement("BookmarksLoad",
        dict.Select(kv => new XElement(kv.Key, kv.Value)));

    XElement Bookmarks = XElement.Parse  ("<bookmarks><key>value</key></bookmarks>");
    Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (var el in Bookmarks.Elements())
    {
        dict.Add(elBookmark.Name.LocalName, elBookmark.Value);

    }
```

Problem is, i can not add elBookmark.Name.LocalName

Comment: Your code doesn't save anything?

Comment: Now i tried this code:

Comment: Your newly added code does doesn't attempt to save anything either. Where is the code that creates the XML that doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, if i understood you, you wish to save an integer and a string in a single xml file, and read them back later.
This could be done very much easely with an XmlSerializer.

I've created a model class:

```
public class ConfigElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And now I'm able to serialize and deserialize it like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigElement() { Id = 6, Value = "Hello World" };
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(config.GetType());

        serializer.Serialize(File.CreateText("myXml.xml"), config);
    }
}
```

The XML generated by this is similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigElement>
  <Id>6</Id>
  <Value>Hello World</Value>
</ConfigElement>
```

Now, if you wish to desirialize this, simply call:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigElement));
var config = serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenText("myXml.xml")) as ConfigElement;
```